# Robocopy permission denied as I cannot traverse folders

Tags: migration, cifs, robocopy

I am in the process of migrating few NAS shares from one storage to other. I am using robocopy to do the migration. Let me try to explain the issue. Sorry in case if its lengthy.

I have cifs share created in my source share\nas-strg1\data. Once we create this share we provide this to the team and they create multiple folders underneath and setup Security and Special permissions as required. All I have access is to \nas-strg1\data and I cannot open \nas-strg1\data\proj1 since they have restriced the access for example. I have my destination \nas-strg1\data with full write access to me. (Everyone Full Control). My expectation is to copy the whole bunch of fodlers to the destination with same permissions. I tried using robocopy with below command and it gives access denied error 5. Can you please suggest best way to do this migration smooth.

I tried /B as well, but my user (domainname\myuser) doesnt seems to be having backup rights.

robocopy "\xx.xx.xx.xx\mytest\testing" "C:\myproj\testing" /E /SECFIX /Copy:DATSO /MIR /IS /IT /log:project.txt /TEE

Do we need to have full traverse permissions? 
Are there any work around?

I have about 800 folders with various permission under each folder. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Please use a account that can access all files. How do you do the backup if even an admin can't look the file ?

If you use a service account for the backup, use the robocopy under that account.

If anything fail, please take ownership of the drive to be able to copy the data, but be aware you might have to redo from stratch the security on the new drive.

Comment: Thanks for quicker response. I am thinking to have a AD level account and try. If not I need to take ownership. But the issue is they have restricted taking ownership in special permissions. That being said, can you please advice any other solution. Also taking ownership on 800 folders which has data of about 50TB will take weeks. Are there any other solution to do the same

Comment: Also can you please point me to taking ownership steps or Microsoft link. Sorry I am new to Windows.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why don't hey just give you the permissions you need to copy the files and folders?

Comment: Also taking ownership on 800 folders which has data of about 50TB will take weeks. That's one reason they wanted to explore. Infact the total data to be migrated is about few hundreds to TB.

Comment: @Mig_sat If any admin account cant read the data, you have no backup. You need an access. Like joeqwerty told, ask them access in worst case.  (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc753659.aspx)

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thank you very much for your suggestions. The strange thing is many folders don't even have access to look at the owner details. Security Tab, Permissions Tab, Current OWner -- None of them are able to show the data. It says permission denied. So I guess I need to get a account which has privileges to take ownership. So if my user has got Special Permission set at AD level for take ownership, will I be able to take ownership myself?

Comment: And taking ownership will affect the existing ownership and permissions? Or my user will just get added?

Comment: @Mig_sat Use a domain admin account to test please.

Comment: thank you. Will ask for a domain account and give a try.